# How to replace all apostrophes in an excel sheet with double apostrophes

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have to export excel sheet to ms sql database table. For that I used oledb connection . It works well. But any cell value containing apostrophes(example : cell 1 value is - divya's ) shows an error “Unclosed quotation mark after the character string” . 
I found that To insert single quote or apostrophe data in database we need to use two consecutive single quotes or apostrophes in data. How can it make possible in excel sheet ?

```
 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) //upload QB
{
    SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();      
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadExcel.FileName);
    int fileSize = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.ContentLength;
   if ((Path.GetExtension(filename) == ".xlsx" || Path.GetExtension(filename) == ".xls") && (fileSize <= (1.049e+6)))
    {

            string excel_file = "my_excel_file";
            var path1 = Server.MapPath("~/personal/" + excel_file + "");
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path1);
            if (directory.Exists == false)
            {
                directory.Create();
            }

            fileuploadExcel.SaveAs(path1 + "\\" + filename);
            string filepath = path1 + "\\" + filename;
            //Create connection string to Excel work book
            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";


            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
            //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name],[Address] from  [mysheet$]", excelConnection);
            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string name = "";
            string address = "";

            while (dReader.Read())
            {
               name = valid(dReader, 0);
               address = valid(dReader, 1);
               insertdataintosql(name,address);
            }
            excelConnection.Close();       
    }

    else
    {
        Label5.Visible = true;
        Label5.Text = " Only Files Having .xlsx or.xls format and less than 1MB size can be uploaded**";

    }

}
  protected string valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)
{
    //if any columns are found null then they are replaced by zero
    object val = myreader[stval];
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(val, DBNull.Value))
    {
        return Convert.ToString(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
public void insertdataintosql(string name,string address,)
{   SqlConnection conn = obj.getcon();
    conn.Open();
    string query = "insert into sample_test(name,address) values('" + name + "','"+address+ "')"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `valid` function:

Instead of

```
return val.ToString();
```

use:

```
return val.ToString().Replace("'","''");
```